# GZIP decode file with php, have it working just trying to get rid of errors outputted by E_ALL

Tags: php, gzip

I have this function for decoding gzipped files,

```
// GZIP DECODE
function gzipDecode($d) {
    $f = ord(substr($d, 3, 1));
    $h = 10;
    $e = 0;
    if($f&4) {
        $e = unpack('v', substr($d, 10, 2));
        $e = $e[1];
        $h += 2 + $e;
    }
    if($f&8) {
        $h = @strpos($d, chr(0), $h) + 1;
    }
    if($f&16) {
        $h = strpos($d, chr(0), $h) + 1;
    }
    if($f&2) {
        $h += 2;
    }
    $u = @gzinflate(substr($d, $h));
    if($u == false) {
        $u = $d;
    }
    return $u;
}
```

It works as expected but I turned on error reporting and I get these two errors

**Warning: strpos(): Offset not contained in string**

AND

**Warning: gzinflate(): data error**

These warnings refer to the bits of code above that have been error supressed, have any idea on how I can fix them?

Thanks

Comment: Just use [`gzdecode()`](http://php.net/gzdecode) or one of the various user-land implementations. Also you probably wouldn't want to have zero error messages for corrupt input data.

Comment: How can I enable that it says undefined function I have private hosting?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simply using [`gzdecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php)?

Your header decoding looks correct.  You should check that your gzip stream is really starting where you think it does by checking the first three bytes for 0x1f, 0x8b, 8.